# Get SOAP Reply in ASP.NET Webservice

Tags: soap, webmethod

I created a SOAP WebService to receive a request. I want to log the SOAP messages with envelope. 
I discovered how get the request message, but I don't discovered how can I get the reply message.

To get the XML Request, I use the code below.

```
// Create array for holding request in bytes
byte[] inputStream = new byte[HttpContext.Current.Request.ContentLength];

// Read the entire request input stream
HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream.Read(inputStream, 0, inputStream.Length);

// Set stream position back to beginning
HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;

// Get the XML request
string xmlRequestString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(inputStream);
```

To get the reply, I tried do this into the Dispose method, but I couldn't make it work.

Comment: When you say you couldn't make it work, what happened? What was the value of inputStream when executed?

Comment: Thanks for try help. I posted more details.

Answer (score 0):

The InputStream works fine.
The Request SOAP XML I get propertelly. I need a way to get de SOAP XML that my web method replay to the caller. Into the WebMethod the Response is not complet. So I tried use the Dispose Method, but I have the same problem. The dispose method is call before .Net Framework return the reply to caller.
I need a way to log the SOAP XML Request abd the SOAP XML Replay.

The code below get XML Request fine:

```
[WebMethod]
public ActivityCCPResponseOutput Request(ActivityCCPRequestInput ActivityCCPRequestInput)
{
    XmlDocument xmlSoapRequest = new XmlDocument();
    Stream receiveStream = HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream;
    receiveStream.Position = 0;
    StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
    xmlSoapRequest.Load(readStream);

    string xmlSOAPRequest = xmlSoapRequest.InnerXml;

   ...
}
```

In the code below, I couldn't get the reply. Probably, there is a different way to do this.

```
void IDisposable.Dispose()
{
    XmlDocument xmlSoapResponse = new XmlDocument();

    // In this point HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream is empty
    Stream responseStream = HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream;

    responseStream.Position = 0;
    StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
    xmlSoapResponse.Load(readStream);

    string xmlSOAPReply = xmlSoapResponse.InnerXml;
}
```